# Dotnet core genric type parameter inherited mode

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, .net-core

I would like to ask how can I achive such a signature in dotnet?
I have these three methods

```cs
public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<AllianceOpenPosition> allianceOpenPositions, uint allianceId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<SquadOpenPosition> squadOpenPositions, uint squadId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<TribeOpenPosition> tribeOpenPosition, uint tribeId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
```

As you can see the only difference in between the signature is the type of list received as input. All three models are united under a base abstract class called `OpenPositionBase`

I would like to create an interface in order to restrict the object to have the GetOpenPositions method implemented.

I have tried to create something like this

```cs
public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<OpenPositionBase> tribeOpenPosition, uint tribeId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
```

Common base class

```
public class OpenPositionBase
    {
        public uint OpenPositionId { get; set; }
    }
```

AllianceOpenPosition

```
public class AllianceOpenPosition : OpenPositionBase
    {
        public AllianceOpenPosition()
        {
            Alliance = new Alliance();
            LeadRole = new LeadRole();
        }

        public uint Id { get; set; }

        public uint AllianceId { get; set; }

        public uint LeadRoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

This class is the implementation of the IPositionConverter interface where I am looking for to add the GetOpenPositions method in a general way so in the SquadPositionConverter class I could use this method as `GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<SquadOpenPosition> allianceOpenPositions, uint allianceId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)`

```
public class AlliancePositionConverter : IPositionConverter
    {

        public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPositions(IEnumerable<AllianceOpenPosition> allianceOpenPositions, uint allianceId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
        {
            return allianceOpenPositions.Where(w => w.AllianceId == allianceId)
                                        .Select(s => new Position(orgOpenPositionList.FirstOrDefault(wh => wh.Id == s.OpenPositionId))
                                        {
                                            Id = s.Id.ToString(),
                                            AgileRole = s.LeadRole.Name,
                                            AgileRoleRank=s.LeadRole.Rank
                                        }).ToList();
        }
```

and all the rest of the classes have a similar structure.

and than change in each object the param to the inherited model. Unfortunately it gives and error.

Any possible solution other than create all three and implement only the one needed?

Comment: What error message does it give you? It would also be good to see what you've written for `OpenPositionBase`

Comment: The error message for this case is that the object does not implement the interface.

Comment: This question lacks some fairly key details. Can you paste the concrete classes, the base class/interface and give an explanation of what this method does and what similarities the classes have.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure what you're exactly after but:

You can make the method generic itself:

```
public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPos<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, uint tribeId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList) where T : OpenPositionBase
```

Then you can work with your list as if it was an open position base

or you can create a generic interface:

```
public interface IGetOpenPos<T> where T : OpenPositionBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPos(IEnumerable<T> list, uint tribeId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList);
}

public class AlianceOpenPosition : OpenPositionBase, IGetOpenPos<AlianceOpenPosition>
{
    public IEnumerable<Position> GetOpenPos(IEnumerable<AlianceOpenPosition> list, uint tribeId, IEnumerable<agile_shared.RequestModel.OpenPosition> orgOpenPositionList)
    {
        // implement
    }
}
```